# Template with default value of method pointer argument

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, pointer-to-member

Consider this special container class that stores types that contain both key and value inside it, so

```
template<typename K, typename T, K (T::*method)() const>
class Container
{
//...
};
```

K is the type of a key, T is a type of value and the method pointer is used to retreive the key from the value.

It works fine but I would like to include a default for the method pointer so that when it was not specified by the caller it would be `operator K() const` like so:

```
template<typename K, typename T, K (T::*method)() const = &T::operator K const>
```

but this does not compile stating there is `no member operator const K on A (<- my class I test this with)` when I try to instantiate it (and there is such a method). Is it even possible to have default value of a method pointer template argument? If yes, what is the correct syntax?

EDIT: In addition to the solution below there is a "fix" for the cases when T is a pointer that uses new C++11 feature `std::remove_pointer<T>::type`, so:

```
template<typename K, typename T, K (std::remove_pointer<T>::type::*method)() const = &std::remove_pointer<T>::type::operator K>
```

Comment: The idea is [sound in principle](http://ideone.com/fgtF5y). It may just be a matter of spelling the name of the particular function (the conversion function) correctly.

Comment: [There](http://ideone.com/k1bCEJ), maybe remove the `const`?

Comment: `operator K const` (== `operator const K`) would be a conversion function to, well, `const K`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the function is just `operator K`. Its qualification isn't part of the name. Try:

```
template <typename K,
          typename T,
          K (T::*method)() const = &T::operator K>
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Good point: the name of the member does *not* involve the qualifiers (or the arguments). If it is necessary to resolve an overload, that needs to be done via the conversion to a suitable member pointer (which is, conveniently, readily available in this case).

Comment: Right, of course. Now it works except when I use pointer to T as argument. I guess specialization should help with that though.

Comment: And I figured it out for cases when T is a pointer as well. Added as edit to the OP.